# How can I list all available charts under a helm repo?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm repo:

`helm repo list`

> NAME          URL
>
> stable        https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
>
> local         http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts

and I want to list all the charts available or search the charts under `stable` helm repo.

How do I do this?

No command so far to list available charts under a helm repo or just verify that a chart exists.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First, **always** update your local cache:

```
helm repo update
```

Then, you can list all charts by doing:

```
helm search repo
```

Or, you can do a case insensitive match on any part of chart name using the following:

```
helm search repo [your_search_string]
```

Lastly, if you want to list all the versions you can use the -l/--version argument:

```
# Lists all versions of all charts
helm search repo -l 

# Lists all versions of all chart names that contain search string
helm search repo -l [your_search_string]
```

Comment: `helm search repo` doesn't work. Outputs `Usage:
  helm search [command]`

Comment: The same for `# Lists all versions of all charts
helm search repo -l `

Comment: @Snowcrash. Works for me: 
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.7.2", GitCommit:"663a896f4a815053445eec4153677ddc24a0a361", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.17.3"}

Answer (score 18):

You can use [helm search to search for Helm charts](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-search). There is an interesting option that you can pass to `helm search` that will let you use regex to search for Charts. That way, you can pass a regex that matches with any Chart name. For example

```
helm search repo -r ".*"
```

That will show all the Charts on all repositories.

You can additionaly use `--devel` flag with above command to show development version charts

Comment: As of Helm v3 the `-r` flag does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: `helm search repo -r [regex]` is what I use with helm 3.x.

Answer (score 7):

As of Helm v3x, seems like the easiest method would be to:

`helm search repo $repoName -l`

Should produce a list of packages within the specified repo (`$repoName`); then, to further specify a package name:

`helm search repo $repoName/$packageName`

That should narrow results down to something manageable.

Comment: i don't know why this answer isn't more highly rated; it's the only one that works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **grep** as well as follows.

Get a list of all of the repos added.

```
helm repo list
```

Update your repos

```
helm repo update
```

Search for 'nginx' in all of the repos that you have

```
helm search repo nginx
```

List all the packages in bitnami

```
helm search repo bitnami
```

Finally you can use grep to filter out in a given repo

```
helm search repo bitnami | grep nginx
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for:

> helm search

In your case

> helm search stable

or

> helm search local

**EDIT:** Doc link: https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#helm-search-finding-charts

Answer (score 3):

you can do a "helm search repo" .
I am using helm version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.1"}
Hope it helps

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Kiril1512 Why's that?

Comment: @KartikShah look at another responses quality and this response...

Answer (score 2):

Having gone through all the answers in this question, the answer seems to be:

> You can't.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need helm at all to accomplish this.

Let's say you're trying to find the list of packages in `https://charts.helm.sh/stable/`.

Just add `index.yaml` to the URL, so you get `https://charts.helm.sh/stable/index.yaml`. This contains a list of everything in the repo.

Additionally, [you can use `yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to get this data in a more useful format:

```
$ curl https://charts.helm.sh/stable/index.yaml | yq --compact-output '.entries | to_entries | .[].value[] | {name, version}'
{"name":"acs-engine-autoscaler","version":"2.2.2"}
{"name":"acs-engine-autoscaler","version":"2.2.1"}
{"name":"acs-engine-autoscaler","version":"2.2.0"}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To list all the available charts for a specific application, you can try below command:

- Repository - stable
- Application - sample-app

  helm search stable/sample-app -l

Answer (score 1):

Helm 2: `helm search -r '\vstable/.*\v'` [(1)](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-search)

Helm 3: `helm search repo -r '\vstable/.*\v'` [(2)](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_search_repo/)

From the documentation:

> To look for charts with a particular name (such as stable/mysql), try searching using vertical tabs (\v). Vertical tabs are used as the delimiter between search fields.

Answer (score 0):

Add the repo and search it:

```
$helm add <repo> <repo url>

$helm search --regexp <repo>/*
```

Replace repo with the repo you want to search, say jetstack

```
$ helm search --regexp jetstack/*
```

Comment: `helm search --regexp some-repo/*
zsh: no matches found: some-repo/*`

Comment: @Snowcrash I am using helm ```v3.2.1``` and this flag seems to have been removed. if you want to search for something, just use ```helm search repo <chart-name>```. but you still need to add the repos you want to search from.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `helm search repo` to list all the charts and `helm search repo search_text` to list charts based on the input search text.

For Example: `helm search repo my_chart`

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

- `helm repo update`: for updating the repos.
- `helm search repo <repo_name>`: for seeing all the helm charts that are in `<repo_name>` repo.

Answer (score 0):

Manual and hacky way:

- `helm repo update`
- Find the cache path for your operating system at the bottom of the docs https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/
- Find the file <repository_name>-charts.txt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to add:
If you'd like to list the develop versions (like 1.0.1-1234), you need one more parameter: --devel

For example:

```
helm search repo ingress-nginx --devel -l
```

Otherwise the develop versions will not be listed.